# Parse error: syntax error Line 39

Tags: php, wordpress

At the bottom of all my blog posts I get this comment:

COMMENTS

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/nildcan/public_html/wp-content/themes/memorability/comments.php on line 39

(Can be viewed on site here: http://www.nildcanada.org/courses/#comments)

I believe it's the last line that is the problem, but I don't know what's wrong. Here is line 39/40:

```
        <div class="commenttext"> <?php if(function_exists('get_avatar')) { echo get_avatar($comment, '56', $default = '<http://www.nildcanada.org/wp-content/themes/memorability/images/davatar.jpg>'); } ?>
        <?php comment_text() ?>
```

Can anyone help?!

Answer (score 0):

You define an variable directly in an function, that does not work. Try this:

```
<div class="commenttext"> 

<?php 
    if(function_exists('get_avatar')) { 
        $default = 'http://www.nildcanada.org/wp-content/themes/memorability/images/davatar.jpg';
        echo get_avatar($comment, '56', $default);
    } 
?>

<?php comment_text(); ?>
```